# JS how to get twitter's name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to get the twitter's name in twitter.

Twitter use this code for every user.

```
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">kya</span>
```

So I did this, but it doesn't work

```
let pa = document.getElementById("css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0");

for (elt of pa) {
  console.log(elt.textContent)
}
```

Also there are a lot of tags with those class name, how could I know if it's the name what I'm getting?

Comment: You're using `getElementById`. Does the element **have** an id?!

Comment: The list of classes is not an ID... Also, it's not guaranteed that this collection of classes is *only* to be found when styling a display name. Nor is it guarananteed to stay the same.

Comment: @Quentin I see, what about getElementsByClassName()? it looks like the for doesn't itterate. (Sorry for my english, also I'm pretty new in js, so sorry for that as well)